# Calendar Dates in TableView with Infinite Scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, calendar, tableview

I am trying to implement to show the calendar dates in `TableViewCell`. I am able to achieved the filled with current year. But As soon I  hit the bottom of the table I need to populate next year and if I hit at top of `TableView` then previous year should be populated.

Pasting code which I have implemented.

```
- (void)fillDatesWithCalendarUnit:(NSCalendarUnit)unit withDate:(NSDate*)date
{
    NSDate *today = date;
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

    NSDate *beginning;
    NSTimeInterval length;
    [calendar rangeOfUnit:unit startDate:&beginning interval:&length forDate:today];
    NSDate *end = [beginning dateByAddingTimeInterval:length-1];

    [self fillDatesFromDate:beginning toDate:end];
}

- (void)fillDatesFromDate:(NSDate *)fromDate toDate:(NSDate *)toDate
{
    NSAssert([fromDate compare:toDate] == NSOrderedAscending, @"toDate must be after fromDate");

    NSDateComponents *days = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

    NSInteger dayCount = 0;
    while(YES){
        [days setDay:dayCount++];
        NSDate *date = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:days toDate:fromDate options:0];

        if([date compare:toDate] == NSOrderedDescending) break;
        [_dates addObject:date];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData]; //_dates mutableArray
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.dates.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    AgendaCustomCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.date.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_dates[indexPath.row]];
    if (indexPath.row ==  _dates.count-1) {
        NSLog(@"load more");
        NSDate *tomorrow = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:(48*60*60) sinceDate:_dates[indexPath.row]];
        NSLog(@"last daye - %@ ,tomorrow - %@",_dates[indexPath.row],tomorrow);
        [self fillDatesWithCalendarUnit:NSCalendarUnitYear withDate:_dates[indexPath.row]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Hi Sandy. 
Do you really need infinite dates? I think most of people will be more than satisfied if they have say 100 years or even less! Then you don't have to worry about infinite issue. You can calculate for another fixed number of years.

Comment: I need almost 100 years, other wise it will fail in automation testing. right?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the logic for show infinite future dates on scrolling.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _dates  = [NSMutableArray new];
    [self fillCurrentYear];
}

- (void)fillCurrentYear
{
    [self fillDatesWithCalendarUnit:NSCalendarUnitYear withDate:[NSDate new
                                                                 ] isLoadMore:NO];
}
```

## pragma mark Private methods

```
- (void)fillDatesWithCalendarUnit:(NSCalendarUnit)unit withDate:(NSDate*)date isLoadMore:(BOOL)isBool
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
    NSDate *beginning;
    NSTimeInterval length;
    if (isBool) {
        beginning = _dates[[_dates count]-1];
    }
    [calendar rangeOfUnit:unit startDate:&beginning interval:&length forDate:date];
    NSDate *end = [beginning dateByAddingTimeInterval:length-1];

    [self fillDatesFromDate:beginning toDate:end];
}

- (void)fillDatesFromDate:(NSDate *)fromDate toDate:(NSDate *)toDate
{
    NSAssert([fromDate compare:toDate] == NSOrderedAscending, @"toDate must be after fromDate");

//    NSMutableArray *dates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSDateComponents *days = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

    NSInteger dayCount = 0;
    while(YES){
        [days setDay:dayCount++];
        NSDate *date = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:days toDate:fromDate options:0];

        if([date compare:toDate] == NSOrderedDescending) break;
        [_dates addObject:date];
    }

//    _dates = dates;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}




- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    AgendaCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.date.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_dates[indexPath.row]];
    if (indexPath.row ==  _dates.count-1) {
        NSLog(@"load more");
        NSDate *tomorrow = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:(48*60*60) sinceDate:_dates[indexPath.row]];
        NSLog(@"last daye - %@ ,tomorrow - %@",_dates[indexPath.row],tomorrow);
        [self fillDatesWithCalendarUnit:NSCalendarUnitYear withDate:tomorrow isLoadMore:YES];
    }

    return cell;
}
```